# A numeric string as array key in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to use a numeric string like `"123"` as a key in a PHP array, without it being converted to an integer?

```
$blah = array('123' => 1);
var_dump($blah);
```

prints

```
array(1) {
  [123]=>
  int(1)
}
```

I want

```
array(1) {
  ["123"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Comment: Since PHP is loosely typed, `"123"` == `123` for almost every purpose.  What's the reason you want it specifically as a string (and having an int is bad)?

Comment: Reason that comes to my mind relates to array functions like `array_merge` *"If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, **however, the arrays contain numeric keys**, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended."*

Comment: Another example where numeric strings as array keys is problematic: [`asort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force PHP to use strings for array keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445953/how-can-i-force-php-to-use-strings-for-array-keys)

Comment: @nawfal: I'd be tempted to close these the other way around. And/or maybe have a mod merge the answers. Or possibly just [let them be.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Comment: This poses a problem for me too when I later array_merge two arrays with specific number strings as keys, as array_merge resets these keys.

Comment: Another use case: unit testing JSON data transition. Converting such an array to JSON and back won't let you assert that both, the original and the result are exactly the same.

Comment: @ircmaxell I have a  library that is doing strict checks on array keys.

Comment: I was curious if `array_change_key_case($array)` would work but alas the internal rules are unhackable (directly).

Comment: @swenedo [`asort()` is just fine](https://3v4l.org/4a5I4), same output since PHP 4.3.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

No; no it's not:

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> A key may be either an integer or a string. If a key is the standard representation of an integer, it will be interpreted as such (i.e. "8" will be interpreted as 8, while "08" will be interpreted as "08").

**Addendum**

Because of the comments below, I thought it would be fun to point out that the behaviour is *similar* but not *identical* to JavaScript object keys.

```
foo = { '10' : 'bar' };

foo['10']; // "bar"
foo[10]; // "bar"
foo[012]; // "bar"
foo['012']; // undefined!
```

Comment: It looks like there is a way, actually! Do you disagree with this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/35180513/247696

Comment: How?!..  foo[012] return "bar"

Comment: @Himanshu: because php interprets numbers beginning with 0 as octal. so 012 is octal 10.

Comment: Yes its possibe using this code:

$dtmf_arr = array();
        foreach ($_POST['dtmf'] as $val)
        {
            $dtmf_arr['"'.$val.'"'] = $dtmf[$val];
        }

Comment: Furthermore, there are plenty of ways to work around this, such as using array addition with `+` instead of merge, or the many inbuilt functions that preserve keys. If you need the key as a string again when reading from the array, casting it to a string is guaranteed to return the original value.

Comment: JavaScript behaves much more reasonably – it only allows single type (string) as object keys so casting everything to string is fine. PHP casts keys differently based on the string contents – that is just cursed.

Answer (score 59):

Yes, it is possible by array-casting an `stdClass` object:

```
$data =  new stdClass;
$data->{"12"} = 37;
$data = (array) $data;
var_dump( $data );
```

That gives you (up to PHP version 7.1):

```
array(1) {
  ["12"]=>
  int(37)
}
```

(Update: My original answer showed a more complicated way by using `json_decode()` and `json_encode()` which is not necessary.)

**Note the comment**: It's unfortunately not possible to reference the value directly: `$data['12']` will result in a notice.

**Update**:
From PHP 7.2 on it is also possible to use a numeric string as key to reference the value:

```
var_dump( $data['12'] ); // int 32
```

Comment: Direct access of the value with a string key doesn't work, though.  Add this line to your example: `echo $data['12'];`.  It will give the error, "Notice: Undefined offset: 12 in - on line 5".

Comment: Yes, you're right. Assuming it was possible sometimes in the past.

Comment: when U use laravel dd($data) it will crash :P

Comment: Upvoting for the cool solution, but it's relatively complicated and I fear that as soon as some bozo that can do something about it notices the answer, it will be marked as a bug.

Comment: In PHP 7.2.0RC2 the behaviour is the same as before.

Comment: It can't be referenced?! Waves hand: "This is not the fix you are looking for".

Comment: Apparently `array_key_exists` won't find it in the older versions either.

Comment: on php7.2.4, `array_key_exists('12',$data)` returns `true`

Comment: This does only work for >5.0 <7.1.33

Comment: My use case is months where I want '01' through '12' as keys in many places, but the reverse order in one place. The original order works now (12/2022), but array_reverse() does not work on objects and really breaks on the original array. A nasty solution could be `array_flip(array_reverse(array_flip($original)))` as I have only the (unique) month names as values.

Answer (score 13):

My workaround is:

```
$id = 55;
$array = array(
  " $id" => $value
);
```

The space char (prepend) is a good solution because keep the int conversion:

```
foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
  echo $key;
}
```

You'll see 55 as int.

Comment: Or `"0$id" => $value`. Prepending with `0` works too.

Comment: So you're saying that it is not possible to use a numeric string like "123" as a key in a PHP array, without it being converted to an integer?

Comment: @Flimm Yes, it's not possible. Not with `array` type anyway.

Answer (score 12):

If you need to use a numeric key in a php data structure, an object will work.  And objects preserve order, so you can iterate.

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$key = '3';
$obj->$key = 'abc';
```

Comment: This is a very good suggestion. I am writing framework code and faced with someone passing an array that could have either "accidental" indexing: array('this', 'that') or "associative" indexing: array(123=>array('this', 'that')). Now, thanks to you, I can just typehint ;) +1

Comment: But is it possible to use a numeric string like "123" as a key in a PHP array, without it being converted to an integer?

Comment: @Flimm no that is not possible, which is why I offer my solution.

Comment: @Flimm that answer seems to contradict the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php): _Strings containing valid integers will be cast to the integer type. E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8. On the other hand "08" will not be cast, as it isn't a valid decimal integer._, although I have not tested his answer.

Comment: That sentence is under the section "Specifying with `array()`, so I'm assuming that *in that context* strings specifying valid integers will be cast to the integer type. But it turns out there are other ways of creating arrays, where that doesn't happen, such as in David's answer, which I have tested.

Comment: @Flimm it sounds risky to me to build code based on tested behavior which the manual says the data structure may not support.  To me, this is akin to depending upon javascript engines to support object property order, which is not officially supported and is implemented differently in different versions and different platforms.  In other words, David's answer may not work in other versions of PHP, and it may stop working if you upgrade PHP in the future.

Comment: And now most array functions are unavailable to you.

Answer (score 5):

You can typecast the key to a string but it will eventually be converted to an integer due to PHP's loose-typing. See for yourself:

```
$x=array((string)123=>'abc');
var_dump($x);
$x[123]='def';
var_dump($x);
```

From the PHP manual:

> A key may be either an integer or a string . If a key is the standard
>   representation of an integer , it will be interpreted as such (i.e.
>   "8" will be interpreted as 8, while "08" will be interpreted as "08").
>   Floats in key are truncated to integer . The indexed and associative
>   array types are the same type in PHP, which can both contain integer
>   and string indices.

Comment: The conversion is not due to loose typing; php determines whether the string *looks* numeric and then converts it.

Comment: So are you saying it's not possible? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35180513/247696) shows that there is a way to use use a string that looks like an integer as a key in an array.

Comment: IMHO the problem is the PHP interpreter. It's not even possible to imagine to have a language that mixes strings and integers as array keys. The best solution? As proposed by Undolog http://stackoverflow.com/a/15413637/1977778 the best solution is to use a trailing space... Sadly.

Comment: @sentenza: It _**is**_ possible to imagine, especially since PHP allows a mixture of strings and integers as the keys of an array: `[42 => 'answer', 'snafu' => 'fubar']`

Comment: @LS yep. I know that PHP allows you to do so, but if you consider the keys within an hypothetical generic type system it won't match any *mixed type* that embraces strings and numbers at the same time. The **loose typing** applied to the keys of an associative array is simply error prone.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem trying to merge arrays which had both string and integer keys. It was important that the integers would also be handled as string since these were names for input fields (as in shoe sizes etc,..)

When I used `$data = array_merge($data, $extra);` PHP would 're-order' the keys. In an attempt doing the ordering, the integer keys (I tried with `6` - `'6'`- `"6"` even `(string)"6"` as keys) got renamed from 0 to `n` ... If you think about it, in most cases this would be the desired behaviour.

You can work around this by using `$data = $data + $extra;` instead.
Pretty straight forward, but I didn't think of it at first ^^.

Comment: The exact same problem led me to this page, but I have to say that this is not answer to OP's question.

Comment: @Flimm True. But searching for an answer led me to this page. I figured my solution could be a help for other Googlers :)

Answer (score 1):

As workaround, you can encode PHP array into json object, with JSON_FORCE_OBJECT option.

i.e., This example:

```
     $a = array('foo','bar','baz');
     echo "RESULT: ", json_encode($a, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

will result in:

```
     RESULT: {"0" : "foo", "1": "bar", "2" : "baz"}
```

Comment: A caveat to this is that it will also force all child arrays to be objects which may not produce the intended output, see [the difference between `json_encode($a, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)` and `json_encode((object) $a)`](https://3v4l.org/2F02S).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem on an array with both '0' and '' as keys.  It meant that I couldn't check my array keys with either == or ===.

```
$array=array(''=>'empty', '0'=>'zero', '1'=>'one');
echo "Test 1\n";
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    if ($key == '') { // Error - wrongly finds '0' as well
        echo "$value\n";
    }
}
echo "Test 2\n";
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    if ($key === '0') { // Error - doesn't find '0'
        echo "$value\n";
    }
}
```

The workaround is to cast the array keys back to strings before use.

```
echo "Test 3\n";
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    if ((string)$key == '') { // Cast back to string - fixes problem
        echo "$value\n";
    }
}
echo "Test 4\n";
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    if ((string)$key === '0') { // Cast back to string - fixes problem
        echo "$value\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Strings containing valid integers will be cast to the integer type. E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8. On the other hand "08" will not be cast, as it isn't a valid decimal integer.

**WRONG**

I have a casting function which handles sequential to associative array casting,

```
$array_assoc = cast($arr,'array_assoc');

$array_sequential = cast($arr,'array_sequential');

$obj = cast($arr,'object');

$json = cast($arr,'json');



function cast($var, $type){

    $orig_type = gettype($var);

    if($orig_type == 'string'){

        if($type == 'object'){
            $temp = json_decode($var);
        } else if($type == 'array'){
            $temp = json_decode($var, true);
        }
        if(isset($temp) && json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE){
            return $temp;
        }
    }
    if(@settype($var, $type)){
        return $var;
    }
    switch( $orig_type ) {

        case 'array' :

            if($type == 'array_assoc'){

                $obj = new stdClass;
                foreach($var as $key => $value){
                    $obj->{$key} = $value;
                }
                return (array) $obj;

            } else if($type == 'array_sequential'){

                return array_values($var);

            } else if($type == 'json'){

                return json_encode($var);
            }
        break;
    }
    return null; // or trigger_error
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The associative array keys will still be integers if the key is a valid integer

Answer (score 0):

Regarding @david solution, please note that when you try to access the string values in the associative array, the numbers will not work. My guess is that they are casted to integers behind the scenes (when accessing the array) and no value is found. Accessing the values as integers won't work either. But you can use array_shift() to get the values or iterate the array.

```
$data = new stdClass;
$data->{"0"} = "Zero";
$data->{"1"} = "One";
$data->{"A"} = "A";
$data->{"B"} = "B";

$data = (array)$data;

var_dump($data);
/*
Note the key "0" is correctly saved as a string:
array(3) {
  ["0"]=>
  string(4) "Zero"
  ["A"]=>
  string(1) "A"
  ["B"]=>
  string(1) "B"
}
*/

//Now let's access the associative array via the values 
//given from var_dump() above:
var_dump($data["0"]); // NULL -> Expected string(1) "0"
var_dump($data[0]); // NULL (as expected)
var_dump($data["1"]); // NULL -> Expected string(1) "1"
var_dump($data[1]); // NULL (as expected)
var_dump($data["A"]); // string(1) "A" (as expected)
var_dump($data["B"]); // string(1) "B" (as expected)
```

Comment: Which php version ? I tried exactly your example and the key `"0"` becomes `0` with php `7.2.10`.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem while trying to sort an array where I needed the sort key to be a hex sha1.  When a resulting sha1 value has no letters, PHP turns the key into an integer.  But I needed to sort the array on the relative order of the strings.  So I needed to find a way to force the key to be a string without changing the sorting order.

Looking at the ASCII chart (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) the exclamation point sorts just about the same as space and certainly lower than all numbers and letters.

So I appended an exclamation point at the end of the key string.

```
for(...) {

    $database[$sha.'!'] = array($sha,$name,$age);
}

ksort($database);
$row = reset($database);
$topsha = $row[0];
```

Comment: So are you saying it's not possible to use a numeric string like "123" as a key in a PHP array, without it being converted to an integer?

Comment: No - it only treats the key that is all numbers as an integer when sorting the array using ksort() - it is never converted to an integer - just compared as one during sorting.