# PHP parse_ini_file

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, ini

I try to parse something from a file, and can't get it to work..

If i do:

```
$idd = 11;
$aInifile = parse_ini_file('status.ini', 'reply');
echo 'test : ' . $aInifile['reply']['11'];
```

Then i get the correct reply. 
But if i use:

```
$idd = 11;
$aInifile = parse_ini_file('status.ini', 'reply');
echo 'test : ' . $aInifile['reply'][$idd];
```

Then it do not work... So how can i get it working, using the $idd variable?

My .ini file

```
[reply]
0 = "In progress (a normal message submission, with no error encountered so far)"
10 = "Delivered upstream"
11 = "Delivered to mobile"
```

Have tried a lot of things, also searched on Google, so betting on help from you guys here!

Comment: Show us ini file. Also the second argument must be a bool value, not string.

Comment: Try `var_dump($aInifile);`. What does that output look like?

Comment: '11' !== 11   (string vs int)

Comment: added a part of the .ini

Comment: @LukeMills: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4100765/259457 - In an array, if a key is the standard representation of an integer, it will be interpreted as such (i.e. "8" will be interpreted as 8, while "08" will be interpreted as "08").

Comment: Show us `var_dump($aInifile)`

Comment: Please var_dump($aInifile). It will show exactly what the type of the key is. As @Travesty3 points out, it shouldn't matter whether the key is a string or an int, but there's probably something going on that var_dump should show.

Comment: @LukeMills http://pastebin.com/kETVHEmd

Comment: @sectus http://pastebin.com/kETVHEmd

Comment: 'Then it do not work...' - what does it mean? Error message?

Comment: @sectus If i use "echo 'test : ' . $aInifile['reply'][$idd];" i do not get any Error message, but just the "test " text from the echo, and nothing more..

Comment: Turn on all errors with using error_reporting.

Answer (score 0):

The index is a string, so you can do this:

```
$idd = "11";
...
echo 'test : ' . $aInifile['reply'][$idd];
```

Note that 11 !== "11"

Comment: According to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), "Strings containing valid integers will be cast to the integer type. E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8. On the other hand "08" will not be cast, as it isn't a valid decimal integer." It's not a strict comparison. http://codepad.viper-7.com/UtLvnw

Comment: Yes, $idd = "11"; did the trick.. But the "clue" is that i get $idd out of an page that i "save" to the variable $idd using curl, so is there a way to add "" to the number (ex the number 11)inside the $idd variable?