# php - How to differentiate between associative and standard array when key is '0'

Tags: php, arrays, types, key, key-value

```
$value = array( '1' );
$value = array( '0' => '1' );
```

These are the two possible formats of arrays that will be passed to the function below. The first is for lists of items (1, 2, 3...) and second indicates a span (1 - 50). With those values, the function worked fine. But not if the span array is from 0 to X as shown above.

There are countless instances of both array types all over the place. This is the relevant part of the function that handles them

```
if ( is_array( $value ) )
{
    if ( $value[0] || $value[0] === '0' )
    {
        echo 'item array';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'span array';
    }
}
```

I have tried these answers: [How to check if PHP array is associative or sequential?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173400/how-to-check-if-php-array-is-associative-or-sequential/)

Which also work where the above function does, but cannot seem to differentiate between the arrays shown above.

This topic explains most of whats going on: [A numeric string as array key in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100488/a-numeric-string-as-array-key-in-php)

Am I unable to differentiate between the two arrays within the code provided? What am I not getting here?

Comment: Are you talking about [**this**](https://3v4l.org/iQBtI)

Comment: The `0` index in your definition above is interpreted as a number, so `var_dump($value)` gives `array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" }`.

Comment: @Uchiha and syck, thanks I now see that here: https://3v4l.org/bk3Pg. So the two arrays are basically the exact same? What I'm asking just can't be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer of the linked question already answers yours:

[A numeric string as array key in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100488/a-numeric-string-as-array-key-in-php)

This is the important sentence:

> If a key is the standard representation of an integer, it will be interpreted as such

#### That means

```
array( '1' )
```

is equal to

```
array( 0 => '1' )
```

is equal to

```
array( '0' => '1' );
```

---

The solution to your problem is to restructure your code:

1. Do not use the same variable for different purposes
2. Do not squeeze everything into arrays

If I understand your "span" data structure correctly, it is something like `array('0' => 1, '1' => 50)` to represent *"1-50"*. Then I would recommend to refactor it into a simple value object:

```
class Span
{
    private $from, $to;
    public function __construct($from, $to)
    {
        $this->from = $from;
        $this->to = $to;
    }
    public static function fromArray(array $array)
    {
        return new self($array[0], $array[1]);
    }
    public function getFrom() 
    {
        return $this->from;
    }
    public function getTo() 
    {
        return $this->to;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, duplicate topic for sure. Sorry.

Comment: I added a suggestion to your concrete problem, hope that makes the question and answer more valuable.