# Undefined Offset in php while getting array through webservice

Tags: php, arrays, web-services, ionic-framework

Building App in Ionic and webservices in PHP. My issue is I am getting an object from the app while hitting the api.

```
[option] => stdClass Object
        (
            [228] => 19
            [229] => 22
            [230] => 24
            [231] => 26
        )
```

In **php** I convert this object to array using the following code..

```
$option = (array)$this->request->post['option'];
```

Then I check its type, it is an array. But When I am trying to get the value of `$option[228]` it returns me an error **"Undefined Offset:228"**. The issue may be it is finding the index value 228 rather than matching the associative key value..

How I can get the value using these numeric keys??

Comment: `var_dump($option)` to see what's in the variable.

Comment: array(4) {
  ["228"]=>
  string(2) "19"
  ["229"]=>
  string(2) "22"
  ["230"]=>
  string(2) "24"
  ["231"]=>
  string(2) "26"
}

Comment: echo $option["228"]; and done.

Comment: <b>Notice</b>: Undefined offset: 228 in <b>file.php</b> on line <b>578</b>

Comment: not working... don't knw why

Comment: @Dave - Why would that resolve it? PHP will automatically convert a string which could be an integer to an int key like [this answer explains](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4100765/2233391). `$option["228"]` can also be accessed by `$option[228]`.

Comment: @henders I have read that thread too.. But didn't understand what is the issue in my case?

Comment: Can you access the value before convert it to array? Like $option->288?

Comment: check what you get from $option->288 before covert in to array

Comment: try to print $option in foreach loop.

Comment: $option prints keys and values in foreach... I have tested that...

Comment: did you get value of $option->$value ?

Comment: @Simerjit Parmar has right. I have test it and when you convert an object, with number as properties, to array you can not access the keys, even if they exist when `var_dump`. Smells like php bug, but not sure yet

Comment: @RK12 I'm trying to display it $option["228"], didn't work...

Comment: try this may be it will help you ,https://3v4l.org/9PY4J

Comment: Thanks @Dave.. Code is working when I create array in php, but it is not working when I am getting data using POST method in webservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate workaround is you can prepare array and then access it's key -> value pair if you require it's keys as well then, like below...

```
$option = array_combine(array_keys((array)$option), array_values((array)$option));
```

Then you can access it's elements like $option[228]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_values($option)` to reset the keys.

```
[
  0 => 29
  1 => 22
  2 => 24
  3 => 26
]
```

Or use the object like this:

$option->{228}

Comment: I can't reset the keys as I need them further too to match with the database records...

Comment: Any other option to use this object as an associative array?

Comment: You may change JSON structure to be something like: `[{id: 228, value:29}, ...]`