# array_key_exists error baffling

Tags: php, arrays, array-key-exists

This is quite possibly NOT something that can be reproduced through a copy & paste. The issue I am having here is that `array_key_exists` simply is not working.

I have printed my code to the page; it is definitely of type array, not that that is required. The array key exists; I have cast between both string & integer and it is coming back not found.

Now, where it becomes most puzzling is that I have iterated between

```
$presets    = $this->presets->$name;
echo gettype($version).'<br>';
foreach ( $presets as $key=>$test ) {
    if ( $key===$version ) echo 'string found1<br>';
    elseif ( $key==$version ) echo 'string found2<br>';
}
if ( !array_key_exists($version,$presets) )
    echo 'array_key_exists string fail.<br>';

$version = intval($version);
echo gettype($version).'<br>';
foreach ( $presets as $key=>$test ) {
    if ( $key===$version ) echo 'int found1<br>';
    elseif ( $key==$version ) echo 'int found2<br>';
}
if ( !array_key_exists($version,$presets) )
    echo 'array_key_exists int fail.<br>';
```

Output:

```
string
string found1
array_key_exists string fail.
integer
int found2
array_key_exists int fail.
```

The output is absolutely strange because in both the `int` & `string` searches, the key matches. In fact, in the `string` search, it outputs "string found1", meaning that it === a key within the array. So, then, why is `array_key_exists` ALWAYS producing `FALSE`?

The variable `$presets` is some array whose indices are created using preg_match regex codes to parse the indices. That is the only added mystery I can come up with, though a manual comparison has proved that an === value was discovered, and therefore none of this should matter. `array_key_exists` should return `TRUE`

```
  Array
  (
      [100] => stdClass Object
          ()
  )
```

Comment: What is the content of `$presets`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. But I also can't create an array whose key is a numeric string. Whenever I try to set the key to a string like `"100"`, it becomes the integer `100`. And your `var_dump()` shows a numeric key as well.

Comment: "_$presets is some array whose indices are created_...". Is it possible that presets is an object that is traversible? What are the outputs of `gettype($presets);`?

Comment: Reproducible when `$presets` is an `stdClass`: `php -r '$p = (object)["100" => new stdClass]; var_dump(array_key_exists("100", $p), array_key_exists(100, $p));'`

Output: `bool(false), bool(false)`

Comment: @Barmar Maybe like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35180513/2734189

Comment: @Don'tPanic Interesting. But that doesn't seem to be what's going on here, since the `var_dump()` shows an integer key. But his `foreach()` loops indicate that it's a string key. Something is not right.

Comment: the array listed is the dump of $presets. I am going to look into the answer below about "numeric-strings" being a thing in <7.2 ... hmm. Thank you this far!

Comment: EDIT:
I have discovered something that appears to be sweeped under the rug and I don't know the solution necessarily just yet. This is apparently a fatal PHP error albeit apparently only *briefly* encountered. `get_object_vars` was used to convert my `object` to an `array`, and according to a bug report in PHP 7.1, `array_key_exists` won't work with numeric keys from said `get_object_vars` conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the results you got from `$key==$version` and `$key===$version`, we know that the key is a numeric string. So it appears you are using a version of PHP < 7.2.

In those versions, you can't reference a numeric string array key, and `array_key_exists` will return `false` whether you give the key in numeric or string form. [This confusing behavior was improved with PHP 7.2.](http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php#migration72.incompatible.object-array-casts)

[Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/WaqF5) illustrating this, based on the example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35180513/2734189).