# How to check if an (int) array key is set by default or is a custom (int) key?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$arr = ['item_one', 'item_two'];
```

By default those keys are `0` and `1` and if i dump that array it looks like this:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "item_one" [1]=> string(8) "item_two" }
```

Instead of first `$arr` default key `1` i want to set it to `25` and then identify the fact that it was set instead of automatically generated:

```
$arr = ['item_one', '25' => 'item_two'];
```

I tried this:

```
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    if(is_int($k)){
        echo '[' . $k . '] is not a custom key!'.
    }
}
```

But the output is:

```
[0] is not a custom key!
[25] is not a custom key!
```

Because obviously both keys are `(int)`.

How do i get key `25` to not output that message?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4100765

Answer (score 1):

Can you try my code:

```
$arr = ['item_one', '25' => 'item_two'];
$i = 0;
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    if($i != $k){
        echo '[' . $k . '] is a custom key!';
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: duck typing is going to mess with you. Use `!==`

Comment: @TimMorton Use `! = `Can exclude the key `0` and correctly find out that `25` is a custom key in this case, Not all cases should use `! ==`.

Comment: @CalosKao um, this proves that 1 != 25.  That doesn’t prove it’s a string (or a so called custom key).

Comment: @TimMorton I agree that this snippet cannot prove that the custom key is a string, and that this snippet will not work if the array length exceeds 26.

Comment: ...and what if `$arr = ['item1','25'=>'item2','2'=>'item3'];`?

Comment: This code will not work if i want to set a custom key to `0` or as @TimMorton said in a descending order.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from some trickery with objects that may or may not work, the only solution I can see is to make duck typing work for you instead of against you:

Prepend a space or 0 in front of the number.  It will then be a string in the key `" 25"` or `"025"`, but will convert to an integer if you use it as a number or cast it as an integer elsewhere.

```
php > $arr = ['item_one', '025' => 'item_two'];
php > foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
php { if(is_int($k)) {
php { echo '['.$k.'] is not a custom key!';
php { }
php { }
[0] is not a custom key!
php >
```

Simply comparing the key to the position within the element is not reliable:

```
php > $arr = ['item_one','25'=>'item_two','2'=>'item_three'];
php > $i=0;
php > foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
php { if($i != $k) {
php { echo '['.$k.'] is a custom key';
php { }
php { $i++;
php { }
[25] is a custom key
php >

(note:  missed $arr['2'])
```

According to the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-57):

> The key can either be an integer or a string. The value can be of any type.
>
> Additionally the following key casts will occur:
>
> - **Strings containing valid decimal integers, unless the number is preceded by a + sign, will be cast to the integer type. E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8. On the other hand "08" will not be cast, as it isn't a valid decimal integer.**
> - Floats are also cast to integers, which means that the fractional part will be truncated. E.g. the key 8.7 will actually be stored under 8.
> - Bools are cast to integers, too, i.e. the key true will actually be stored under 1 and the key false under 0.
>   Null will be cast to the empty string, i.e. the key null will actually be stored under "".
> - Arrays and objects can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type.
>
> If multiple elements in the array declaration use the same key, only the last one will be used as all others are overwritten.

Comment: Hey @TimMorton, so basically there's no other way to set a key as a string when using digits in php except for duck typing? :(

Comment: @emma I added the manual reference to the answer.  Duck typing is going to work hard to prevent what you're wanting to do, unfortunately.  The only way I know to force a number string to remain a string is to prepend a space, zero or plus sign.

Comment: this is so sad ... i think i;m going to use some character that will be removed inside that foreach. Wouldn't it make more sense to be a string if encapsulated by "" ?