# 0 number has not been entered into the mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a script to upload data from csv file to a column in mysql database, pin_code. The pin_code is set to varchar and while inserting into the db, the number 0 before any value has not entered into the db.

for example 012345, was entered as 12345. The pin_code strlen is 6 digits. Any mysql statement to make the change to such columns if the strlen is 5, to add a 0 in front of it? The database is live now. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
UPDATE table_name SET pin_code=CONCAT('0',pin_code) WHERE LENGTH(pin_code)=5
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I was actually writing another php script to fix this but this works great for me!

Comment: What if the pincode is only 4 characters?  This isn't a particularly generic solution.

Comment: This is exactly what was asked for.

Comment: Just for reference I didn't give you the -1.  While the OP did specifically mention 5 character pin codes, he may simply have not had any cases with only 4 character pin codes yet.  It's better to solve the problem rather than put a band aid over it.

Comment: Endophage, i needed a band-aid right now since the website was live and i had to make the change quick.

Answer (score 2):

If you want leading zeroes in PHP, you can use `sprintf()`.

```
$number = sprintf('%06d', $number);
```

[I blogged about this once :)](http://www.alexanderdickson.com/blog/2010/03/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeroes-in-php/)

Comment: As far as I know, PHP will convert that straight back into an integer and strip the leading 0's back off.  Have you actually tested this or was that blog post just a thought?

Comment: @Endophage [It works](http://codepad.org/9QetpOld), but you *have* to have the number as a string.

Comment: @Endophage - the `0` will only be stripped if the string is used in a numeric context, e.g., `$number = $number + 5;`

Comment: Interesting.  I came across a situation that I found very frustrating.  When using a number (typed as a string) as an array key it automatically gets converted into a numerical index.  However, if you use a numerical index for memcached then query the cache with an array of keys, the returned array has the numerical keys as string types.  It caused all sorts of problems because I wanted to do an array_diff_key to get an array of the non-cached items but that function does === so the type check failed.

Comment: @Endophage Thank you, and [something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445953/how-can-i-force-php-to-use-strings-for-array-keys) has happened to me before. :)

Answer (score 2):

Another MySQL solution: use [`LPAD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) for variable-length strings:

```
mysql> SELECT LPAD('123', 6, '0');
+---------------------+
| LPAD('123', 6, '0') |
+---------------------+
| 000123              |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select LPAD('12345', 6, '0');
+-----------------------+
| LPAD('12345', 6, '0') |
+-----------------------+
| 012345                |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP script is most likely stripping the 0 off the front when you read the numbers into PHP.  This is a standard (and royal) pain.  There's literally nothing you can do, at least as far as I know, to stop PHP interpreting a string that contains only numbers as a number and stripping off non-significant figures.

Your suggestion of checking the `strlen` and padding it out is certainly the quickest fix.