# How to convert array index key from [] to ""

Tags: php, arrays

I am stuck somewhere in arrays. I am getting an array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => name
    [1] => description
)
```

And I want to convert that into :

```
Array
(
    "0" => name
    "1" => description
)
```

I have found on google enough for this but did not found any solution, and don't think it is object array.

Can someone please help me out in this.

Thanks

Comment: I am still not getting any solution for this on that link. Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [duplicated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445953/how-can-i-force-php-to-use-strings-for-array-keys), this is how you should do it

```
$data = array(0 =>'name', 1=> 'description');

$keys = array_keys($data);
$values = array_values($data);

$stringKeys = array_map('strval', $keys);
$data = array_combine($stringKeys, $values);
var_dump($data);
```

Output

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(4) "name" 
    [1]=> string(11) "description" 
}
```

There is a small syntax error there- `array_map($keys, 'strval')` should be `array_map('strval', $keys)`

BTW, I don't understand why you need this:

```
$data = array("name", "description");

echo $data[0]; // output: "name"
echo $data["0"]; // Also output: "name"
```

So in both cases you get the same output

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Maybe i didn't understood the question correctly. Doesn't the OP requested to convert the array keys to strings?

Comment: I want to convert [0] to "0" because, I have 2 arrays and I further want there difference by array_diff. and array_diff does not accept array index as [0]

Comment: @addy I suggest you should update the question white this important information, and explain why do you think it's not a duplicate. You should also **include the code that doesn't work** because people like to see what have you tried before asking the question (You can combine it with the code from my answer) - This will reopen your question and allow us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You're misreading the output. The keys are not `[0]` and `[1]`; they are the integers `0` and `1`, stylised for debug output.

You can have string keys instead if you like (i.e. `["0"]` and `["1"]` in the output), but since PHP will coerce between the two as needed anyway, there's really no point.