# Convert javascript object keys to real int after JSON encoded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
var a = {};
a[1] = 1;
a[4] = 4;
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

then I get:

```
{"1":1,"4":4}
```

but I want to get:

```
{1:1,4:4}
```

how to reach this? In other words, I want to keys be real int.

Comment: Object keys are _always_ strings.   No such thing exists.

Comment: ... and thus that last code example is invalid JSON.

Comment: now way to convert to array?

Comment: If it's useful, you can declare `a` as an array (`[]`) and get back `[null,1,null,null,4]` after *JSONification* - which when parsed pack will give the expected values at those *indices*.

Comment: What is the purpose of why you need that format? Do you want to send to the server that way, are you trying reference them a specific way later?

Comment: Looks like some serverside handmade json parser issue :)

Comment: right, solution is here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445953/how-can-i-force-php-to-use-strings-for-array-keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call JSON.stringify() method it creates a valid JSON string.
One of the rules for valid JSON is that every property should be in "quotes".

So thats why it is impossible to get such result as you want using JSON.stringify.

If you want to just convert such object to array it is possible, for example usin such function.

```
function numerableObjectToArr(obj) {
  var result = [];
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  keys.forEach(function(item){
    result.push(obj[item]);
  })
  return result; 
}

var a = {};
a[1] = 1;
a[4] = 4;
numerableObjectToArr(a); // returns [1, 4]
```

But in this way you will just receive Array with values of existing properties in the obj.

But if your prop name means the index in the array, and you are sure that there will be always number as a prop name - you can improve this function:

```
function numerableObjectToArr(obj) {
  var result = [];
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  keys.forEach(function(item){
    result[+item] = obj[item];  //we put index, then we put value to that place in array
  })
  return result; 
}

var a = {};
a[1] = 1;
a[4] = 4;
numerableObjectToArr(a);  // returns [undefined, 1, undefined, undefined, 4]
```

Comment: yea, I see, I realized that its a server-side issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445953/how-can-i-force-php-to-use-strings-for-array-keys

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do what you're trying to do the as the keys have to be string values. I'd advise having string name for your keys (i.e 1 = One, 2 = Two, etc). You could then try this:

```
 var a = {};
    a.one = 1;
    a.two = 2;
    a.three = 3;
    a.four = 4;

    console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var a = {};
a[1] = 1;
a[4] = 4;
alert(JSON.stringify(a).replace(/\"([0-9]+)\":/g, '$1:'));
```

But it is kludge. JSON - has a string keys.

Comment: You can't parse JSON with regex.

Comment: it is not parsing. It is converting.

Comment: Yes, that's the point. To do it properly, you need to parse it, and then use a custom stringifier. You don't want [Zalgo to come](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630), do you?

Comment: I dont see any troubles to use regexps for replacing in JSON. But replacings in JSON - it is bad by itself.

Comment: I value this help, though Im not keen for raping JSON either.