# Why does array_count_values silently turns strings to int?

Tags: php

Here is an array with **only strings**:

```
$array = ["1", "hello", "1", "world", "hello"];
```

Notice that `"1"` is a string.

If I use `array_count_values` on this array, it seems it *silently* converts *strings to ints*.

```
var_dump(array_count_values($array));
```

Echos:

> array(3) {
>     [1]=>
>     int(2)
>     ["hello"]=>
>     int(2)
>     ["world"]=>
>     int(1)
>   }

`1` is now an int. I feel it's a weird behavior. Is it normal? Did I missed something? **Is there a way to avoid this behavior?**

Comment: This might actually not be `array_count_values`, but the mechanism of arrays turning numeric indices into numbers.

Comment: Look this question maybe : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100488/a-numeric-string-as-array-key-in-php or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445953/how-can-i-force-php-to-use-strings-for-array-keys

Comment: @iainn Not really a duplicate I think. Since it's about a specific function (that roughly turns key into values), I feel it could help other users. Still, it's a good link, thank you.

Comment: @deceze Ok thanks. I think you could post your comment as an answer with some links to relative question and I will accept it (or I could write it if you prefer)